# Accessing text of sibling element

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to web scraping, and currently I'm struggling so hard to get a particular element of text.

This is a piece of html I'm using and I'm trying to get an information whether a day of weekend contains  element with "Closed" text.

[image]

I tried so many things and I couldn't get further than getting elements of Saturday and Sunday. Is there a way how to somehow access text of sibling elements of those I already retrieved or some other way for this?

```
timetable = soup.find_all('th', text=["Sat", "Sun"])

for day in timetable:
    print day.find_next_sibling('td').text.strip()  /// this doesn't work
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You could have pasted elements other than the image. It's of no use.

Comment: what do you mean? I was pretty sure this piece of code is enough to get to the element I need, but if you clarify what's wrong with it, I can fix that. I'm not really sure you want whole html page, since it's right from yelp.com website and it's pretty complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `find_next_sibling()` use `find_next('td')`:

```
timetable = soup.find_all('th', text=["Sat", "Sun"])

for day in timetable:
    td = tr.find_next('td')
    if(td.text == 'Closed'):
        print(day.text,'Closed')
```